# Changing formatting string from % to alternate character?

Tags: python

In python 2.6, is there a way to specify an alternate character other than % for string formatting operations? Or is the % char hardcoded in the python interpreter?

For example, to generate a string that looks like this:

```
param1%02param2%03param3...
```

I currently have to do this:

```
str = "%s%%02%s%%03%s" % (param1, param2, param3)
```

What I'd like to be able to do is substitute, say, ^ for % and be able to do:

```
str = "^s%02^s%03^s" ^ (param1, param2, param3)
```

which IMO is far more readable.

Comment: changing the language syntax in an attempt to be more readable will backfire, because other readers of your code won't be able to read it at all. Consider other methods of making it more readable!

Comment: Why not use a different character than %0 for your seperator, and then replace that sequence with %0, after doing your formatting e.g. `str = "%s|2%s|3%s" % (param1, param2, param3)
` `str = str.replace('|','%0')`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the new `str.format` method. It offers more formatting options and is more readable.

```
>>> '{0}%02{1}%03{2}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')
'a%02b%03c'

>>> '{param1} is also {param2}'.format(param1='foo', param2='bar')
'foo is also bar'

>>> '{0[name]} is {0[age]} years old'.format({'name': 'Bob', 'age': 42})
'Bob is 42 years old'
```

For more information, check the documentation: [Format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: I totally agree with you. Definitely this would be the best way to format strings nowadays, as the % operator is getting deprecated.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. Sure the new format string syntax is nice, but I doubt the old one inherited from C is going anywhere. Furthermore, the new syntax just doubles the issue, now you have to escape `{` and `}` instead.

Comment: @Matt How something that __really__ works doesn't answer the question?? The issue was with `%` not with `{` and `}`. Just because you don't like something that is right it doesn't means you should downvote it.

Comment: @Matt BTW, if you don't like the new syntax you should move away from python because the `%` operator got deprecated on Python3.

Comment: I hardly think old-style string formatting being described as _may go away in future versions of Python_ is a reason to stop using Python3. I might mention I use Python3 exclusively, get paid to do so, and prefer neither formatting syntax.

Comment: @Matt I might mention I also get paid to write both Python 2 and 3 applications and your arguments make no sense at all. Do you even read what you write? lol

Answer (score 2):

`%` is hardcoded. You could, however, do something like...

```
your_str = ("%s^02%s^03%s" % (param1, param2, param3)).replace("^", "%")
```

or

```
your_str = ''.join([param1, '%02', param2, '%03', param3])
```

Comment: @Dani - you should look at what code is actually there. The `%` signs in the code example I gave do not need to be escaped; they're where things *are* supposed to be substituted. The replacement occurs *after* the substitution.

Comment: I prefer the `join` method, because it won't blow away a `^` that might properly be in one of the `param` variables...

Comment: Hail the str.format(). I believe that ''.join() was never meant to server these kind of formatting purposes.

Comment: For simply joining together a sequence of items, `join()` was entirely meant for that.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with JBernardo's answer, however, for completeness I just wanted to point out that it is indeed possible to adapt the language to the questioner's needs. That involves deriving a class from `str` and overriding its `^` operator:

```
class yourstr(str):
    def __xor__(self, tuple):
        return self.replace("%", "%%").replace("^", "%") % tuple
```

Then you can do something like:

```
>>> param1 = "foo"
>>> param2 = "bar"
>>> param3 = "quux"
>>> yourstr("^s%02^s%03^s") ^ (param1, param2, param3)
'foo%02bar%03quux'
```

I wouldn't recommend doing that in the general case, though, since it makes the code harder to read and maintain.

Answer (score -3):

You can't - its not even hard-coded in python, its hard-coded somewhere in libc (a level below the interpreter). You could write a function that will the string with the `^` and convert them to `%` and take the existing `%` and convert them to `%%` and then pass it to formatting.

Comment: No, it's not.  The formatting code is part of Python; see eg. PyString_Format in stringobject.c.

Comment: What has libc to do with Python strings?

Comment: @Franklin: libc used to do a lot of the work behind Python's string formatting.  It does much less now.